# Ubuntu 20.04 on which machine should I amend my samba smb.conf configuration file since all machines on network have one

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing, shared-folders, sharing

I have found many useful articles referring to the smb.conf file to change the operation/characteristics of Samba on Ubuntu 20.04 - but none specify on which machine.

Common sense would say just the machine on which the folders/files are shared. But I worry that if I start my 'satellite' laptop, ie the one accessing the shared files but not hosting them, then the local .conf will be loaded and override the one on the shared laptop. Or maybe it works the other way around and the opposite happens.

Maybe certain changes must be made on one and some on the other - or maybe I need to amend all so they are the same.

I am just confused by having multiple smb.conf files, one on each machine, and which ones I should change and when.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The server needs a `smb.conf` to specify what is shared and to whom. The client doesn't need an smb.file.

Comment: @Jos - if you want to post that as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share files between Ubuntu systems you will need Samba installed on the server. Samba comes with a configuration file `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. Configuring Samba is tricky because of the many possibilities. However, for simple file sharing, all you may need to do is to add a short segment to the config file. Mine is just this:

```
[share name]
path = /path/to/shared/files
valid users = jos
read only = no
```

which is sufficient for clients to have read and write access to the files and folders under `/path/to/shared/files`. Clients will have a line in their `/etc/fstab` to mount the share at boot time, referring to `//[IP address of server]/share_name`, and some form of credentials to log in as user `jos` on the server.

On the clients, you only need to install `cifs-utils`, not the whole Samba package. Unless, of course, they act as servers themselves, which is unusual. So feel free to remove (purge) the Samba package on the clients.